# function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and I have this error:

**"openClose is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index:13)"**

I searched up every possible answer to this, but the thing is that the error is in the index page and not in any of the app files.
I will paste my code here in hope that someone knows what to do.

app.component.html

```
<button id="btn1" class="btn1" onclick="openClose(this, 'bg-modal')">Click me </button>
    <div class="bg-modal" id="bg-modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="close" id="close">+</div>
        <h2>Modal</h2>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="contents">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
      <div class="confirm" id="confirm">OK</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css',
  './video-style.css']
})
export class AppComponent {}

function openClose(btn1, bgmodal){
    document.getElementById('.btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('.bg-modal').style.display='flex';
    });
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Modal</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried:

- putting the code in app.component.ts in between the brackets of export class AppComponent {}
- in the index.html leaving only
- putting the code of the click in  tags in index.html and then it works with 0 errors

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how it should be. :

```
<button id="btn1" class="btn1" (click)="openClose($event, 'bg-modal')">Click me </button>
```

In Component.ts file.  :

```
public openClose(event, bgmodal){
       .... rest of code 
    }
```

Note that : Direct accessing of DOM element is not recommended in Angular.

Just to make your scenario working adding a Stackblitz demo  : [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iegqys)

Comment: this makes much more sense considering Angular and typescript, but now my error is `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`. Can you help me with this too?

Comment: @kaja111 what is ur requirement ?  what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I am trying to make a modal, with clicking on "btn1" the "bg-modal" should become visible, while it usually is hidden with css. I was doing this with just html and javascript and it worked, now I'm trying to transform it to a angular component..

Comment: @kaja111 which library you are using. ? is it bootstrap ?

Comment: Thank you! With your demo everything is working how I wanted it to! I see now that I tried to make it more complicated than it really needed to be, cons of being a newbie. Thank you for your time and help

Comment: Thanks in my case I missed id attribute in button tag after adding it is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

`onclick` at button can not call function of component, it must call with javascript code, eg: `onclick="console.log('sss')"`

If u want to call to function of component:

.html:

```
<button id="btn1" class="btn1" (click)="openClose(this, 'bg-modal')">Click me </button>
```

.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css',
  './video-style.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    openClose(btn1, bgmodal){
        document.getElementById('.btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
            document.getElementById('.bg-modal').style.display='flex';
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular you should mention which event you want to use. If you want to use click event then you should use like this :

```
<button (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
```

because angular doesn't have any event like

**onclick**